# current month is invalid angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the below directive to check if its past month/year or not? I am watching the `ccinfo.month,ccinfo.year` model.

```
angular.module('app').directive('cardExpiration', function() {
    var directive = {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch('[ccinfo.month,ccinfo.year]', function(value) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('invalid', true)
                if (scope.ccinfo.year == scope.currentYear &&
                    scope.ccinfo.month <= scope.currentMonth
                ) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('invalid', false)
                }
                return value
            }, true)
        }
    }
    return directive
})
```

The current month `August` fails to `check`. Previous month `July` passes and `September` passes. Why this code saying the `current month as invalid?`

Comment: What is the type of `scope.currentMonth` and `scope.ccinfo.month` ? Are you comparing month names?

Comment: May be because `'A'<'S'`?